# How many places of power are there and what bonuses do they grant you? 

Tags: the-witcher-2

There are various places of power that grant a bonus to Geralt distributed around the map. The vicinity of a place of power is indicated by a characteristic sound effect, if you activate your medaillon you can see them as a red mist. If you step into this red mist while the medaillon is active, you are granted one of the possible bonuses.

I didn't find any place where the exact nature of each bonus was noted. How many different places of power are there and what are the bonuses they grant you?
[image]

Comment: When I step into them, a name flashes in the lower left corner. I.e., "Circle of Life activated!"

Comment: @Raven And then Elton John burts into song ♪ "Its the circle of life..." ♪

Comment: One is in the Dungeons in the prologue, don't remember the name, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found four. Circle of Power, Life, Endurance, and Vigor.

Respectively, they seem to increase melee damage, Vitality, armor value, Vigor regeneration.

I'll see if I can't get some definite values hammered in as well.

Edit: Okay, preliminary testing has provided some results

**Circle of Life** -- 2 Vitality Regeneration (out of combat) / 1 Vitality Regeneration (in combat)

**Circle of Endurance** -- 3 Armor

**Circle of Power** -- 120% sign intensity? (So maybe +.2, since I had 1 sign intensity before?)

**Circle of Vigor** --  +300 duration (possibly x2 duration)

Comment: Are you talking about the ones in Floatsam Forests (in Chapter 1)? Those are actually "Circles of Power" (there's actually [five of them,](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Circle_of_Power) though 2 have the same effect) which have similar effects to "Places of Power," but do not give [the same effects](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Place_of_Power). The Witcher medallion reacts differently to Circles of Power (glow) compared to Places of Power (vibrate).